'Adding' confidence intervals of multiple estimations
I have estimates of the number of injuries seen by ambulance services on a quarterly basis, together with a confidence interval. I want to add these estimations to retrieve one estimation of the total yearly number of injuries as seen by ambulances. How can I calculate confidence intervals around this total?
Every quarter each ambulance service makes N rides. From N a sample of +-1000 cases is taken (n). For each case in this sample, it is determined whether the ride was injury related (1) or not (0; i.e. related to disease etc.). Meaning I can calculate the proportion of injuries in the sample: p̂ = n1/ntotal. To get an estimate of the total number of injuries (lets call this statistic ‘x’) I then multiply p̂ with N.
However, I want to account for uncertainty introduced by taking a random sample, so I use the stats::binom.test() function in R to estimate a confidence interval (CI) around p̂, and multiply the found lower and upper boundary by N to retrieve a CI around x.
So now I have an estimation of x for every ambulance service and every quarter (x1, x2, … xn), which I can sum for a yearly national estimation. However, I am unsure how to ‘add’ the confidence intervals. I am pretty sure that taking the sum will yield an overly pessimistic interval.
I have found this post, which seems to suggest that I could take the square root of the sum of squares of the CIs radius, since I am assuming statistical independence between ambulance services and quarters within a year. But I am not sure if this is correct. Another approach I am considering is to pile all the data of every service and quarter and use that to calculate p̂ and CIs. However, the proportion of injuries are known to meaningfully differ between the services (and quarters) as well as the total number of rides (N). I am not sure if this method will then yield a pessimistic CI as well.
So, how can I use the data to calculate CIs around the total yearly estimation?

You certainly can "pile all the data of every service and quarter and use that to calculate p̂ and CIs". The fact that p̂ is different services and/or quarters is not a problem; each service/quarter will be appropriately weighted in this grand total $x_{total}$ by the respective $N_i$ (total number of rides per service/quarter).
But, there may be (?) a lurking problem. You say that for each service/quarter, you have a sample of size $\pm 1000$, which is rather large. How large is it, in comparison to the total ($N_i$) number of rides for that service/quarter? If 1000 is a meaningfull portion of the total rides (>5-10%?), you may need to use a Finite Population Correction (FPC) in your estimation of the CI's (basically, you go from a binomial distribution -sampling with replacement-, to hypergeometric distribution -sampling w/o replacement-). You may want to look here, here, here, or here (and many other places). A FPC, if warranted, will give you narrower CI's. The FPC would apply to the grand total CI, but also all your by service/by quarter CI's as well.

Thank you! The sample size is definitely a relevant proportion of the total () number of rides. It differs greatly between ambulance services (depending on the size of the region they service), with a range of about 4% - 25%. I will look into FPC, thank you for your suggestion.

I have been looking into FPC, and the correction seems simple enough to apply. However, most sources seem to use it in combination with the Wald method of estimating CIs. I would rather use the Clopper-Pearson 'exact' method as in some cases the proportion of injuries might be very low (long story). Am I correct to assume  that the method does not matter, and that I can simply multiply the 'exact' method's CI 'width' with the FPC?

Yes, you can use the Clopper-Pearson method (in fact, much preferred over Wald), and simply adjust the width of the CI by the FPC. At 4% of total $N_i$, it will not have a big effect; but at 25%, it will seriously reduce the width of the CI
